# what imports needed for Corda Vault Query (Java Code)

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am facing this error.
 error: cannot find symbol 
FieldInfo attributeAccount = getField("accountId",AccountSchemaV1.PersistentAccount.class);

What should i import for getfield?
Already these libraries are imported.

```
import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient;
import net.corda.core.node.NodeInfo;
import net.corda.core.utilities.NetworkHostAndPort;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCConnection;
import net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps;
import net.corda.core.node.services.Vault;
import net.corda.core.node.services.vault.*;
import com.template.states.AccountState;
import com.template.schema.AccountSchemaV1;
import net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef;
import net.corda.core.messaging.DataFeed;
import rx.Observable;
import net.corda.core.node.services.VaultService;
import net.corda.core.node.services.*;
import net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria.*;
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getField` method is available in `QueryCriteriaUtils`.

Use a static import as below:

```
import static net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteriaUtils.*;
```

or it can called as `QueryCriteriaUtils.getField()`

```
FieldInfo attributeAccount = QueryCriteriaUtils.
getField("accountId",AccountSchemaV1.PersistentAccount.class);
```